# Using ThemeProvider on Styled-Components UI Library

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, styled-components, rollup

I'm creating a UI library which uses Styled-components and i have a component like this

```
const Title = styled('div')`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.sender.color};
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.3rem 0.5rem;
  span {
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.sender.color};
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.sender.botBackground};
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
`;
```

I need to implement  in another project, importing the component from my UI Library. I've done all the process to build the library and set it up to be used as a library using rollup and babel.

```
<ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
    <Title />
</ThemeProvider>
```

however when i try to use the ThemeProvider in the project, the *theme* prop is not being passed down and i'm getting an error because it's trying to get *sender* from *undefined*

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner implementation might look something like this:

```
const Title = styled('div')`
  color: ${ props => props.sender.color};
`;

<ThemeProvider theme={defaultMessageBubbleTheme}>
    <Title />
</ThemeProvider>
```